# Wordpress: Display the content custom page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display the content of a specific page using the theme files.
I tried this :

```
$import_page = get_page_by_title(page-title-here);
echo "$import_page->post_content";
```

It works except that it doesnt display the formatting of the page. only text and the images, It avoids the line breaks, paragraph formatting ect.

Thank you for helping me to get this sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `the_content` filter to `post_content` before printing it.

Like so

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $import_page->post_content);
```

You can find out more about [the_content filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).